# Is root of a function differentiable?

Tags: calculus, functions

Let's assume a function $f(\alpha,\theta)$ always has a single zero wrt $\alpha$:

$\forall \theta, \exists \hat\alpha_\theta$ such that $f(\hat\alpha_\theta,\theta)=0$.

Let's now consider this root as a function of $\theta$:

$$g(\theta)=\hat\alpha_\theta$$

Assuming $f$ is differentiable wrt both its variables, is $g(\theta)$ differentiable ?

Thanks a lot for your hints !

Comment: The whole set of assumptions looks rather weak to me...

Comment: The [implicit function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) is the thing you would like to use. However this requires stronger assumptions (like countinious differentiable).

Comment: The assumptions here seem more than strong enough to ensure that $g(\theta)$ is continuous, though.

Comment: @DavidK Functions in two variable sure are intersting: if $f(\alpha,\theta)=(\theta^2 e^\alpha - 1) (\alpha^2 + \theta^2)$, then $g$ is not even continuous.

Comment: OK, maybe those conditions plus a condition that $g(\theta)$ is bounded. For example, you can make $\lim_{\theta\rightarrow a^+}g(\theta) = g(a)$ false by ensuring that $\lim_{\theta\rightarrow a^+}g(\theta)$ does not exist.

Comment: @DavidK Yeah, I guess that works: Because $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is closed, and thus the curve $(\theta,g(\theta))$ is closed. If $g$ is bounded, then $g$ has to be continuous (I guess but I don't have a proof for that right now).

Comment: Thanks a lot for these pointers and interesting discussion, and for the counter-example below as well !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean functions from  $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, a counterexample is
$$
f(\alpha,\theta) = \alpha |\alpha| - \theta^2.
$$
(As the OP requested for hints, proof is left as an exercise.)

---

**Edit:** And $g$ does not even have to be continuous. My idea was to consider two different functions, one of which has a root only for one $\theta$, and the other has roots always except at one point. Then multiplying them would give an example with noncontinuous $g$.

After some thinking I figured out that one way to get a function that has a root always when $\theta\neq 0$ but does not have one when $\theta=0$, is to find a function whose root goes to infinity as $\theta$ approaches $0$.

After some drawing, this lead me to the following example:
$$
f(\alpha,\theta) = (\theta^2 e^\alpha - 1) (\alpha^2 + \theta^2)
$$
When $\theta\neq 0$, the second part is always positive but the first part has the unique root $\alpha=\ln(1/\theta^2)$. When $\theta=0$, the first part does not have a root but the second part has a unique root.

Comment: A nice discontinuous counterexample. I was looking for one too but went about it the wrong way.